# Tracker import says "Trackers have been disabled in this project."

Tags: tuleap

When I click on tracker import under my project it says "Trackers have been disabled in this project."

I see trackers enabled. I did create new trackers as well.

Its a full tuleap latest version installation as per installation guide on virtual box centOS instance.

Answer (score 3):

Caveat emptor, the following applies to the Docker’ized version of Tuleap as available from their site.

I don’t know if this helps the original post or anyone else who has this problem, but the way I was successful in importing Tracker data from a `.csv` file was to first look under the “Manage Field Usage” button in the “Administration” section of the respective “Tracker” - “User Stories” in my case.

When you are in the “Manage Field Usage section you can inspect the individual form fields by clicking on the pencil icon. The field header you need to add to the your `.csv` file is the “Name” item. It is usually lowercase with underscores. The first field in the “User Stories” tracker is `as_a` for example. You need to make sure you include a column for each item that is designated as required by the red asterisk.

The name of the column is highlighted in this image:

[image: The name of the column is highlighted in this image]

The result that "Worked for Me(tm)" was a first line in the .csv file with the following column definitions:

```
title, description, assignee_username, milestone, label1
```

I was able to flawlessly import a `.csv` file with 40 entries into the “User Stories Tracker” this way.

I imagine the other “Trackers” work in a pretty much similar way although I haven't tried them yet.

If there is an easier way to find this information, I haven’t figured it out yet, it certainly doesn’t work the way it is described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This "Tracker Import" relate to the old generation of Tuleap Trackers (aka. Tracker v3) and should be hidden now.

In other words, it's harmless and have no impact

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot import a tracker. So project import will import all the project data ? How do I import the project data then? Please share Project data export and project data import steps together.

Comment: Import tracker functionality (in CSV format) is done inside tracker service in administration. There is no Project data import/export yet.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else finds this issue...

I can verify in version 9.10 that v5 tracker structures can be exported/imported by:

1. Export the tracker structure in the admin section of the target tracker
2. Click create new tracker on the project you wish to import the tracker too
3. Select the "From XML file" Radio button.
4. Select the downloaded XML file.

You can then export/import the tracker artifacts using csv files, although you will loose artifact links.